# Vuetify want to replace excisting global navbar with another navbar when going to a specific route

Tags: vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I want to replace the global default navbar with another navbar when going to a specific route.

This is my code currently:

```html
<v-app-navbar>
    <header v-if="DesktopHeader">
        content
    </header>
    <header v-if= "otherHeader">
        content
    </header>
</v-app-navbar>
```

```js
mounted () { 
    if (this.$nuxt.$route.path === '/page') {
        this.otherHeader = true
    } else {
        this.DesktopHeader = true
    }
}
```

With this code, the page does display the default global navbar, but when going to the designated route it loads both navbars

Answer (score 0):

You are not toggling both variables:

```js
mounted () { 
    if (this.$nuxt.$route.path === '/page') {
        this.otherHeader = true
        this.DesktopHeader = false
    } else {
        this.DesktopHeader = true
        this.otherHeader = false
    }
}
```

The whole logic could be stored in only one variable or some other logic could be implemented (probably a logged out user shouldn't see a header or something).